# Return bool value if it exists in Another table

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have two tables. Appointment and Blacklist. When i blaklist a customer i put his cusId as a foreign key to blacklist table.

```
Appointment
------------
(AppId,Time,CusId)


Blacklist
-----------
(CusId,date)
```

Here the CusId is referenced to Customer . What i want is when i search with appointment id in the Appointment table, if the customer relevant to that appointment is in the blacklist table return true else false.

I am new to EF. Please help me to fix this matter.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int appId = 10; // appID to check

bool ifBlackListed = BlackList.Any(r=> r.CusID == 
                                       Appointment.First(t=> 
                                                         t.AppId == appId)
                                                  .CusId);
```

I am not sure what SQL query would be generated against it, but you can get the `CustId` from appointment first and then compare it in `BlackList`, that *might* save you from sending extra search query on each iteration of `BlackList.Any` like:

```
int custID = Appointment.First(t=> t.AppId == appId).CusId;
bool ifBlackListed = BlackList.Any(r=> r.CusId == custID);
```

Also if you are expecting `null` back from your first query *(against Appointment)* then use `FirstOrDefault` and check against `null` before accessing `CusId`

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. I made some changes.. and it is working now. Thanks.

Comment: @Daybreaker, You are welcome,  I am not sure what query would be generated against it, but you can extract `Appointment.First(t=> t.AppId = appId).CustId` and then compare it with `BlackList`, that would save the extra search on each iteration.

Answer (score 3):

A query like this should work:

```
bool isBlacklisted = 
    (from a in dbContext.Appointments
     join b in dbContext.Blacklist on a.CusId equals b.CusId
     where a.AppId = appointmentId
     select b)
    .Any();
```

But if you have a navigation property set up between your `Appointment` and `Blacklist` entities, this is even simpler. You could do something like this:

```
bool isBlacklisted = 
    (from a in dbContext.Appointments
     where a.AppId = appointmentId
     select a.Blacklist.Any())
    .First();
```

Or possibly even this:

```
bool isBlacklisted = dbContext.Appointments.Find(appointmentId).Blacklist.Any();
```

Answer (score 0):

If foreign keys and entities are setup properly:

```
from a in Appointment
//where a.CustId == customerId //if you want to pass a customer id
select new {Appointment = a, IsBlackListed = a.Customer.BlackList.Any())
```

else:

```
from a in Appointment
//where a.CustId == customerId //if you want to pass a customer id
select new {Appointment = a, IsBlackListed = BlackList.Any(b=>b.CustId == a.CustId)}
```